# Mi aplicacion de rails pierde el javascript y el css de vez en cuando, y tengo que recargarla, que podria ser?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, ruby-on-rails

La mayor parte del tiempo se ve normal pero hay momentos en los que parece que el css o el javascript no cargan y las cosas se salen de su lugar, intente buscar que podría ser pero no entiendo porque, lo único que se me ocurre es que tenga que ver con el orden en que carga las cosas pero creo que si lo fuera pasaría todo el tiempo

Comment: Difícil veo que puedas recibir alguna ayuda con los datos que aportas. ¿has verificado que efectivamente no cargan los css o js en la consola de desarrollo de tu browser? ¿recibes algún error en la consola? ¿de qué manera tienes configurado tu stack en el frontend? ¿vanilla rails? ¿turbolinks? ¿webpacker? ¿otro?. Revisa [ask] para que veas como mejorar tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, para la próxima intentaré formular mejor la pregunta, buscaré como verificar eso que me dices